# docker + openshift

Tags: ubuntu, docker, openshift

Всем привет!

Развернуть RED HAT CONTAINER REGISTRY с локальным хранилищем образов Docker.

Как пользователь Docker я могу работать с registry ( pull, push ) все ок!

Но также, как пользователь я могу загрузить образа с docker hub командой pull.

Например:

```
$ docker pull debian
```

Вопрос:

Как запретить пользователю "тянуть" образа с docker hub и разрешить использовать только внутренний реестр openshift?

Т.е. есть ли возможность настроить какой-либо конфиг, чтобы пользователь обращался к внутреннему репозиторию образов?